# How to format TEAC TC-7120 Tablet

Tags: rooting, tablet

I have  - **TEAC TC-7120** tablet and I want to entirely format it using just with the "volume +/-" and "power" on buttons .

I haven't any approach to its OS since it locked and I don't have any idea about its password or Google account for recovery .

Is there any solution for that ?  I looking for solution like this approach  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtKDpawgeLs (just button using) .

Comment: @Cornelius what does rooting have to do with this? To do a factory-reset via recovery-menu, no root is required. // URL87: You've used the `rooting` tag, but your question is about `factory-reset`. Accident or incident? Also, could you please [edit] your question and include an abstract of what's behind that link? Not everybody here can access Youtube (and furthermore, the video might be removed, or unavailable in some areas). One more thing to include: what have you already tried? What was the outcome, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Askmefast.com](http://www.askmefast.com/How_can_i_do_hard_reset_for_teac_tablet_tc7120-qna4269703.html#q4563363) provides a hardware reset solution for that tablet:

- Power off
- Press and hold **Power** and **Volume Up** together
- When it turns on (nothing may appear on screen or only the logo) release **Volume Up** (keep holding **Power**)
- Keep holding **Power** and press and hold **Volume Down**

This should launch the reset mode and after a restart it should erase all apps and settings.

**Read more:** How can i do hard reset for teac tablet tc-7120? - Tablet teac classic 103 factory reset :: Ask Me Fast at http://www.askmefast.com/How_can_i_do_hard_reset_for_teac_tablet_tc7120-qna4269703.html#q4563363